# Definition of a fan of a polytope

Tags: algebraic-geometry, convex-analysis

In Fulton's book *Introduction to Toric varieties* (page 25), he says that:

> A rational convex polytope $K$ in $N_{\mathbb{R}}$ determines a fan $\Delta$ whose cones are the cones over proper faces of $K$."

I don't quite understand what he means by cones over faces of $K$? Can someone explain this to me or show me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The faces of the polytope are certain subsets of $N_{\mathbb R}$. A fan consists of cones. So to make a cone, we take a face, and define the cone to be $$ \{ \lambda f \mid f \in F , \lambda \in \mathbb R^+ \}.$$

**Example:** Let the polytope be a square with corners $(\pm 1, \pm 1)$. Then the corresponding fan is the fan consisting of the quadrants in $\mathbb R^2$.